# ReferenceError: d3 is not defined in jest Unit Test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, d3.js, jestjs

I have two js files. One is chatbot-pie.js and another one is d3.v5.js(it's a library).

If I run my script in the browser, it's working as expected.

But the problem is when I run `npm test` it's showing "ReferenceError: d3 is not defined"
I am testing my script using jest

My chatbot-pie.js unit test file looks like this:

```
const d3 = require('../../src/base/js/d3.v5');
const cs = require('../../src/base/js/chatbot-pie');
it('call method of chartScript', async () => {
    let details = [{ "name": "XXXXXXXXX", "label": "39" }, { "name": "TNS INVESTMENT", "label": "25" }, { "name": "TNS INVESTM", "label": "20" }, { "name": "GRAND DING HOU", "label": "10" }, { "name": "MI-NE SG HK", "label": "3" }, { "name": "Other", "label": "3" }];
    cs.chartScript(details, '.custom-chart-1');
});
```

I have uploaded d3.v5.js library in below link: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LTMIjIAVTygW4Y8Y_gfUTkxyGweM7t9a

Below one is chatbot-pie.js code

```
function chartScript(details, cls) {
  //Get number of pie chart that alread shown
  let num = parseInt($('.pie-chart-field').val());
  let clsName = 'show-chart-' + num;
  //Add unique class in kai-carousel
  $('.kai-carousel:last-child')
    .find(cls)
    .html("<div class='show-pie-chart " + clsName + "'></div>");
  $('.pie-chart-field').val(++num);
  clsName = '.' + clsName;

  let lblName = new Array(details.length);
  let i = 0;

  //Get lable name from details array and put it in lblName  
  for (let index in details) {
    lblName[i] = details[index];
    i++;
  }

  //Initialize chart width and height
  let width = 350,
    height = 350;

  //Define co label name and color for pie chart
  let colors = d3
    .scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(lblName)
    .range(['#A4A4A4', '#0073AA', '#009DD9', '#005D87', '#00A76D', '#6DC067']);

  //Set svg width and height
  let svg = d3
    .select(clsName)
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);
}
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = {chartScript};
}
```

The errors screen shot is below:

[image]

Comment: I indeed do not see `d3` declared in your `chatbot-pie.js` file

Comment: In browser view, d3 declaration is not required because I already added as an external script. My html page look like and its working fine
example url: http://demo21.tcsesoft.com/
```
<script src="../../src/base/js/d3.v5.js"></script>
<script src="../../src/base/js/chatbot-pie.js"></script>
```

 But when I run the test script, d3 showing as not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely familiar with how you load the script, but it seems related to the context you run the function chartScript in. What happens when you add a console.dir of d3 object before you run the chartScript function? If it is available there, try feeding it to your details object as an extra parameter, so the function has it as an inputparameter?

Comment: Yes, it's working, Just pass d3 as a parameter in chartScript()
thanks a lot @Ivo Sturm